# How to let lower dpi devices to download only their pictures with downloading application?

Tags: android, dpi

I'm making application with task of recognizing pictures. I have many (about 1000) pictures and all of those 1000 pictures are made specially for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi devices, so actually I have like 5000 pictures. It's not problem to make it 5 times, but the problem occurs with application size. Since I'm getting one .apk in bin file, does it mean that ldpi device will need to download xxhdpi images with this .apk which, after all, it won't be using at all.

Maybe I'm wrong with understanding how things go, if so, please tell me. So, how to make that every device downloads pictures with application which it needs, not any other, or is it maybe going automatically?

Comment: You could make use of Multiple APK Support on Google Play: http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put all your resources in the project, the compiled APK will also contain all images. That is not an option for your use case. The APK will be to big.

You have two options:

- You can use APK Expansion files: [APK Expansion files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)
- The other option would be to implement an image server with an API and then use this API in your android app to download each file on request.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this first is great solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you segregate your pictures and put them in the appropriate drawable folder, you'll do fine. See, if suppose you have a xhdpi device, it will access drawable folder `drawable-xhdpi` and doesn't have access to other folders. So just make sure, the right pictures are in the right folders. You don't need to do anything extra about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your image resource in your apk. Of course ,the low dpi cell and the high dip cell use only one apk.

One way can fix it . You can put your image on the line. And when users download your apk and install it, you can download images by different url.
such as: http://yoururl_ldpi.png   http://yoururl_hdpi.png ...

Comment: That would take too long, still idea is theoretically correct.